# Nullspace of a nilpotent matrix $A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n$ where ${A_i}_{i=1}^n$ are nilpotent matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im coming across this small problem in my physics research but I cant seem to prove it and am probably overlooking something.

The problem:

Let $\{A_i\}^n_{i=1}$ be a set of nilpotent matrices such that $A^2_i=0$ for all $1 \leq i\leq n$. If each summation $A_j+A_k$ and $A_j+A_k+A_l$ and $A_j+A_k+A_l+A_m$ and $\dots$ $\sum^n_{i} A_i$ for all $ 1\leq j,k,l,k\leq n$ 
are nilpotent then
$\mbox{Null}(\sum_i A_i)=\bigcap_i\mathrm{Null}(A_i)$.

For my examples it seems to always be true however Im getting stuck proving the non trivial set inclusion,
$\mathrm{Null}(\sum^n_i A_i)\subseteq\bigcap_i\mbox{Null}(A_i)$ to show that
$\mathrm{Null}(\sum^n_i A_i)=\bigcap_i\mathrm{Null}(A_i)$.

Any help or counter examples
would be appreciated! Thanks!

edit 1: I should point out that also included in my assumptions is the fact that no two nilpotent matrices in $\{A_i\}$ are eachothers negatives
i.e. $\{A_1, A_2\}$ such that $A_2=-A_1$ which gives the trivial nilpotent matrix 
$A_1+(-A_1)$.

edit2: Added in the additional property which states that each ''piecewise'' summation of any $A_i$ matrices is itself nilpotent.

Comment: The sum of two nilpotent matrices need not be nilpotent, even if the "nilpotentcy" is order two.  Moreover if A and -A were your two nilpotent matrices, the nullspace of A + (-A) might well be bigger than the intersection of the two (equal) nullspaces.

Comment: Ah yes I know in general the sum of two nilpotent matrices is not nilpotent again. Your example about A+(-A) makes sense but I forgot to edit that in my current situation this is not ''allowed''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $A_1^2 = A_2^2 = 0$ and indeed $(A_1 + A_2)^2 = 0$.  The intersection of the nullspaces of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is dimension 2, while the nullspace of $A_1 + A_2$ is of dimension 3, so the latter is strictly larger.

Comment: Yep thanks I too noticed its fairly easy to construct such a counter example. My matrices have a special form that I dont want to bother anyone with but at least I know that in general as stated above its false. Cheers!

Comment: At least you know that special property has to come into play, to prove what you want.  In effect your Nullspace$(\sum A_i)$ is the smallest possible, which amounts to proving the rank is the largest possible.